# findstr split by space and show 3rd word

Tags: cmd, findstr

On Windows 2012 I am running `net user localusername | findstr "logon"`

which returns `Last logon                   9/8/2017 9:27:16 AM`

I only want it to return the date which will be different on each account. How do I filter this to only return 9/8/2017?

This is what I did for Windows 2016 and it works great, but Windows 2012 does not support grep or cut.

```
net user "{{ item }}" | grep "Last logon" | cut -d' ' -f21
```

which returns `9/8/2017`

**update**
The following is working on the server thanks to @Mofi

```
for /F "tokens=3" %I in ('net user "test" 2^>nul ^| findstr "Last logon"') do @echo %I
```

Comment: In a command prompt window can be executed `for /F "tokens=3" %I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe user "%UserName%" 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /C:"Last logon"') do @echo %I`. Please run `for /?` in command prompt window to understand how `for /F` processes the output of `net` filtered with `findstr`. This command line works only on English Windows as the string `Last logon` depends on language of Windows.

Comment: Thank you @Mofi worked great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update The following is working on the server thanks to @Mofi

```
for /F "tokens=3" %I in ('net user "test" 2^>nul ^| findstr "Last logon"') do @echo %I
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy enough to get the LastLogon timestamp using PowerShell. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell will be available.

This can be put into a .bat file script.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(Get-LocalUser -Name 'pwatson2_la').LastLogon -f 'd'"') DO (SET "LLD=%%~A")
ECHO LLD is %LLD%
```

Comment: is there a way to do this on the command line in a single command? I am sending this via ansible

Comment: The servers I am targeting are on PowerShell version 3.0

Comment: PowerShell 3.0 was released in 2012. Is there any chance it could be upgraded to a modern-day version? Windows PowerShell 5.1 from 2017 is Microsoft's latest.  PowerShell Core 7 is available at http://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/